# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. - tharindu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/rmagick-2.15.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.15.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.15.2'` succeeds before bundling.

E:\redmine-master\bin>gem install rmagick -v '2.15.2'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/rmagick-2.15.2/gem_make.out

Comment: please help me I have tried so many things.. This works for a new rails app but it doesn't work for an existing source code.I used redmine source code for run rails.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
brew install ImageMagick

gem install rmagick
```